# Pass HTML dropdown value to JSTL sql:query

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a HTML dropdown menu where I want to pass the selected values as parameter to the SQL Query.

this is the Dropdown:

```
<select name="ifs_db_options" onchange="submit()">
    <c:forEach var="ifs_db1" items="${ifs_db1.rows}">
        <option value="${ifs_db1.rows}" selected>${ifs_db1.img_hub}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And this is the my query

```
<c:set var="hub" value="${ifs_db1}"/>
<sql:query var="ifs_db" dataSource="jdbc/postgresDB">
    select * from ifs_db where img_hub = ?
  <sql:param value="${hub}" />
</sql:query>
```

I want to pass the parameter from the dropdown "value"

```
<c:set var="hub" value="value of the dropdown"/>
```

So that I can use it as parameter to my query `"where img_hub = ?"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available as request parameter by `${param}` map the usual way with as key the exact name as you've given the `<select>` element.

So given

```html
<select name="ifs_db_options">
```

you can get it as follows in EL

```
${param.ifs_db_options}
```

Please note that the JSTL SQL taglib is [discouraged](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) for normal production apps as it heavily tight-couples the code.

Comment: would it be like this:                                     <sql:query var="ifs_db" dataSource="jdbc/postgresDB">
       
        select * from ifs_db where img_hub = ?

       <sql:param value="${param.ifs_db_options}" />

    </sql:query>

Comment: follow up question.. will it automatically work once I selected one of the options?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you alias it by `<c:set>` or set it straight in `<sql:param>`. EL is just EL. As to the follow up question, assuming that you've put this inside a `<form>`, then yes. You've namely added a JavaScript `submit()` call to the `onchange` event handler of the dropdown. It will only not work when the client has JavaScript disabled.