# How to grab a value of a dropdwon JSP

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu

I want to ask about JSP dropdown option select. Here is the code

```
<c:forEach var="s" items="${ListItem}">
<option value="${s.NAME}"</option>
</c:forEach>
```

and then i had a list of names:

```
<c:forEach var="dok" items="${blockName}">
 <c:if></c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

How to grab the value of above selected option to be use in the next `<c:forEach>` condition? The purpose is if the selected value from the option EQUALS the name from the second list, then [condition].

I'm using spring v2.0 with iBatis DAO.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be available in request parameter by `${param}` map the `<select name="my_options">` element.

```
<select name="my_options" onchange="submit()">
    <c:forEach var="s" items="${ListItem}">
        <option value="${s.NAME}"</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

You can get it from expression language as,

```
<c:set var="myvar" value="${param.my_options}"/>
<c:forEach var="dok" items="${blockName}">
    <c:when test="${myvar=='1'}">
        // Do something
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
        // Your else part
    </c:otherwise>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: does it need to throw the value to function()? because i didn't get the value of myvar

Comment: See [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397832/pass-html-dropdown-value-to-jstl-sqlquery) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396695/get-value-from-drop-down-list-in-jsp-jstl-when-option-and-cout-is-used) for more details.